# footer is not sticking to the ground

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7, elementor

This is how the footer is looking only on the Contact Page of the client's website.
If you notice the footer is not sticking to the bottom of the page and hiding the submit button.

[image]

I have tried below CSS but then it sticks and is always visible with scroll, like sticky nav. If I remove the fixed position it again leaves the bottom and hides the submit button.

```
.footerclass {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

It is only happening on one page i.e. Contact Us page. I am using "Contact 7 form" using elementor.

How can I fix this? So that it always remains on the bottom of the page for all pages no matter how big the form becomes.

Comment: Can you please share website link so I can check

Comment: please share website link or you can put code sample using one of online editor like codepen or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to your main container (from what I can see that's your `.site` class), as well as `min-height: 100vh`. This will allow you to set the footers position to absolute, relative to the main container.
It will always be at the bottom of the content, but not stick when scrolling. Using the min-height will also ensure that even if there isn't enough content to scroll, the footer will still be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It has worsened the problem

`.site-footer {
  position:relative;
 min-height: 100vh
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with style

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .elementor-section.elementor-section-height-full {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Easiest hack would be to add this to your custom css, but with height "auto".

Screenshot from inspector, where it is:

[image: Screenshot from inspector, where it is]

The issue is not with footer, but with content overflowing behind this because of fixed height.

Comment: It is still not working, if I remove `textarea` from the form then it all works fine on every page including `contact page`.

Comment: @paul textarea makes this taller than 100vh and content starts going behind the footer. At the moment it works for me.

If you want pages always to be scrollable (so that there won't be white area below footer), use min-height "100vh" or "calc(100vh - <some>px)"on content, where <some> is header height + footer height. Min-height would let content to grow, when you add inputs there.

Comment: If I use height as `100vh` it is failing on `contact` and if use `auto` it passes on `contact` but fails for `About page`

Comment: @paul You can limit this style to .page-id-339 - your body element has this class on this page. Put this before the rest of css rule selector: `.page-id-339 .elementor-section.elementor-section-height-full {`